# Angular Infinite scrolling

Tags: angularjs, infinite-scroll

Im trying to implement this plunk example for my application http://plnkr.co/edit/p6Dt3yvTq40Vn56AKiqC?p=preview. Here's the client side :

```
$scope.fetch = function($select, $event) {
    if ($scope.loading) {
      return;
    }
    // no event means first load!
    if (!$event) {
        $scope.page = 1;
      $scope.items = [];
    } else {
        //$event.stopPropagation();
      //$event.preventDefault();
        $scope.page += 1;
    }

    $scope.loading = true;
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost/search/books',
      params: {
        q: $select.search,
        page: $scope.page
      }
    }).then(function(books) {
        $scope.items = $scope.items.concat(books.data.items);
    })['finally'](function() {
        $scope.loading = false;
    });
  };
```

But once i reach the end of my results, there's a loop and the scrolling keep fetching my dataBase and return an empty array.

In my backend im sending a value when i reach the limit, but how i can stop the scrolling in the client side once i hit the limit ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.search = 'not specified';
$scope.limit = false;

$scope.fetch = function($select, $event) {
    if ($scope.loading) {
      return;
    }
    // no event means first load!
    if (!$event) {
        $scope.page = 1;
      $scope.items = [];
    } else {
        //$event.stopPropagation();
      //$event.preventDefault();
        $scope.page += 1;
    }

    if($scope.search != $select.search || !$scope.limit)
    {
      $scope.search = $select.search;
      $scope.loading = true;
        $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories',
        params: {
            q: $select.search,
          page: $scope.page
        }
      }).then(function(resp) {
        $scope.items = $scope.items.concat(resp.data.items);
        $scope.limit = resp.data.limitReached;
      })['finally'](function() {
        $scope.loading = false;
      });
    }
};
```

Comment: I have a boolean value instead : $scope.limit = resp.data.items.limitReached, so if the limit is reached, i dont make the http call, but my value still to true when i enter another value in the text box. There's a way to reset the value to false once i enter a new value ?

Comment: Confused. resp.data.items should be an array, right? How can put your limitReached into it? If only you make them together into a new object { limitReached : true/false, items:[] }

Comment: Not it's not an array, it's a boolean. query.items = Array, and query.limitReached = true/false that i both send from my backend. And sorry i meant $scope.limit = resp.data.limitReached and not $scope.limit = resp.data.items.limitReached but you are right, i will merge it with my array items on the client side and let you know.